# JAVA os x Yosemite 10.10 lineSeparator

Tags: java, macos, line, separator, osx-yosemite

I'm testing my desktop application on Yosemite 10.10. and I have a problem with

replaceAll(System.lineSeparator(), "");

I'm  reading a content from a text file and then I need it in one single line, so I decided to remove all line separators.

Works fine with OS X Mavericks but with Yosemite with all current updates the method is underlined red in Eclipse :( and it's not working.

anybody has it and solved it?
regards

Christoph

Answer (score 0):

Check your java version, also which version of java are you using in eclipse, the method used was added in java 1.7, so if you are or compiling to a lower version you need to use `System.getProperty("line.separator")`.

Comment: thanks a lot! that was a problem! I've got Java 8 for Yosemite and the problem is gone!

Comment: It would be nice then if you could accept the answer (even upvote it) :)

Answer (score 0):

check this out if you go here it will install the latest version of java and most things I use as a LAMP developer will now load, as it triggers a command line tool update to appear which i think is what is missing to get most dev things running. (PHPStorm, BREW, Oh MY ZSH etc)

[http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572][1]

Also i noticed that once i installed JAVA and the command line tool update my user migrations now appear to complete and not fail.